# How to set transparency only for background (and not for label)?

Tags: xaml

I have to create popup page like this:
http://prntscr.com/o9gt9k

Almost everything is prity much simple (grid, columns, rows, margins...)
except transparency...
This is what I get:
[image]

Here is my whole code for that certain popup page:
As you can see, in second StackLayout I set background and opacity(that I want only for background)

```
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0"
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
                  Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=-15}"
                         RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                  Property=X,Factor=0,Constant=15}"
                         RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                  Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=-30}"
                         RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                  Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
                         BackgroundColor="#004A57"
                         Opacity="0.5"
                         Orientation="Vertical"
                         Padding="0,0,0,15">

                <Grid Margin="0,10,0,10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                           Text="6.237"
                           FontFamily="{StaticResource FcraftBorgo}"
                           FontSize="36"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           TextColor="Red" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Grid.Row="1"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                           Text="> 56% iznad 6"
                           BackgroundColor="Red"
                           FontFamily="{StaticResource FcraftBorgo}"
                           FontSize="Medium"
                           Margin="10,0,10,0"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           TextColor="White" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                           Text="TRNUTNI PROSEK"
                           FontFamily="{StaticResource FcraftBorgo}"
                           FontSize="Medium"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           TextColor="Red" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Grid.Row="3"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                           Text="6.07"
                           FontFamily="{StaticResource FcraftBorgo}"
                           FontSize="Medium"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           TextColor="Red" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Grid.Row="4"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                           Text="OSVOJENO"
                           FontFamily="{StaticResource FcraftBorgo}"
                           FontSize="Medium"
                           Margin="0,10,0,0"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           TextColor="Red" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Grid.Row="5"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                           Text="7"
                           FontFamily="{StaticResource FcraftBorgo}"
                           FontSize="Medium"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           TextColor="Red" />
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <ContentView BackgroundColor="#004A57"
                 Opacity="0.7"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0"
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
                  Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=-15}"
                         RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                  Property=X,Factor=0,Constant=15}"
                         RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                  Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=-30}"
                         RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                  Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
                         Orientation="Vertical"
                         Padding="0,0,0,15">

                <Grid Margin="0,10,0,10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                           Text="6.237"
                           FontFamily="{StaticResource FcraftBorgo}"
                           FontSize="36"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           TextColor="Red" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Grid.Row="1"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                           Text="> 56% iznad 6"
                           BackgroundColor="Red"
                           FontFamily="{StaticResource FcraftBorgo}"
                           FontSize="Medium"
                           Margin="10,0,10,0"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           TextColor="White" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                           Text="TRNUTNI PROSEK"
                           FontFamily="{StaticResource FcraftBorgo}"
                           FontSize="Small"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           TextColor="Red" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Grid.Row="3"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                           Text="6.07"
                           FontFamily="{StaticResource FcraftBorgo}"
                           FontSize="Medium"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           TextColor="Red" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Grid.Row="4"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                           Text="OSVOJENO"
                           FontFamily="{StaticResource FcraftBorgo}"
                           FontSize="Medium"
                           Margin="0,10,0,0"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           TextColor="Red" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Grid.Row="5"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                           Text="7"
                           FontFamily="{StaticResource FcraftBorgo}"
                           FontSize="Medium"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           TextColor="Red" />
                    <Image Grid.Column="1"
                           Grid.Row="6"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           Source="qr_icon.PNG" />
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

can you do something like this?

```
<Grid>
    <ContentView BackgroundColor=".." Opacity=0.x" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
     <StackLayout>
       ..  Label  in here ..
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank's for answer.
I find some similar solution (mazbe even the same) earlier somewhere, but it' doesnt' work. Do you have some other idea?

Comment: hi, it worked for me in similar situation. not worked at all? did you use it correct?

Answer (score 0):

check this please, worked for me:

```
  <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>


             <StackLayout Grid.Row="0"
                         HeightRequest="500"
                         WidthRequest="500"
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                 <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                     <StackLayout RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
              Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=-15}"
                     RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
              Property=X,Factor=0,Constant=15}"
                     RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
              Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=-30}"
                     RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
              Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
                     Orientation="Vertical"
                     Padding="0,0,0,15" Opacity="0.3"  BackgroundColor="#004A57">


                </StackLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </StackLayout>
        <Grid Margin="0,10,0,10" Opacity="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       Text="6.237"
                       FontFamily="{StaticResource FcraftBorgo}"
                       FontSize="36"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       TextColor="Red" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       Text="> 56% iznad 6"
                       BackgroundColor="Red"
                       FontFamily="{StaticResource FcraftBorgo}"
                       FontSize="Medium"
                       Margin="10,0,10,0"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       TextColor="White" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Grid.Row="2"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       Text="TRNUTNI PROSEK"
                       FontFamily="{StaticResource FcraftBorgo}"
                       FontSize="Medium"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       TextColor="Red" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Grid.Row="3"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       Text="6.07"
                       FontFamily="{StaticResource FcraftBorgo}"
                       FontSize="Medium"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       TextColor="Red" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Grid.Row="4"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       Text="OSVOJENO"
                       FontFamily="{StaticResource FcraftBorgo}"
                       FontSize="Medium"
                       Margin="0,10,0,0"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       TextColor="Red" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Grid.Row="5"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       Text="7"
                       FontFamily="{StaticResource FcraftBorgo}"
                       FontSize="Medium"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       TextColor="Red" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: @NitrusBrio please check this and let me know if worked for you